# How can I resolve this 'Variable DeclaratorID' error?

Tags: java, variable-declaration

I'm trying to implement a program which involves accounting for the minimum amount of words required to legislate for all the diphones in the English language.

I have used a HashSet to create the diphonetic dictionary, which I now wish to convert to a TreeSet in order to sort the diphones. A snippet of the erroneous code is as follows :

```
dictDiphonesSet = new TreeSet<String>(dictDiphonesHashSet);

Set<String> unusedDiphonesSet = new HashSet<String>(diphoneSet);

unusedDiphonesSet.removeAll(dictDiphonesSet);

diphoneSet.removeAll(unusedDiphonesSet);

List<DiphoneticDict> diphoneticDictNoRptDiphones = new ArrayList<DiphoneticDict>();

StringTokenizer subStrDiphone = null;

Boolean diphoneRepeats = false;
```

The offending code is throwing up a 'VariableDeclaratorID' error (dictDiphonesHashSet), an error which is repeated throughout the rest of my code. Can anyone offer me any assistance as to how I might go about legislating for these errors?

I am relatively new to coding and a little bit confused!

Best regards.

Comment: can you post the whole error message?

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> dictDiphonesSet = new TreeSet<String>(dictDiphonesHashSet);
```

unless you have declared the `dictDiphonesSet` variable elsewhere.